# Creating a 2 level navbar using Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, navbar

I am trying to create a 2 level navigation bar with this code but when I try to add another children to one of the children in the scrip it won't work. The idea is for the user to go to a second level where he can select other links. It should hover on link in navbar, then go to the 1st level menu and then hover on one of the option to get the 2nd level menu.

```
  <template>
   <!--  Top menu -->
   <nav
      id="mainNav"
      class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top"
      :class="$route.path==='/home' ? '' : 'bg-primary'"
      >
<!--      <div class="rtl-layout" @click="addToggleClass()"><a href="javascript:void(0);">RTL</a></div>-->
      <div class="container ">
         <router-link class="navbar-brand" to="/home" routerLinkActive="active-link">
<!--            <img src="/static/img/zemle-logo.png" class="img-fluid" width="110" height="37">-->
           <h3 class="text-white" >Sospes Logo</h3>
         </router-link>

         <button
            class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>

         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul id="main" class="navbar-nav ml-auto main-menu list-unstyled">
               <li
                  @click="menuToggleLink('menuNo'+i);"
                  class="parent nav-item"
                  v-for="(menuItem,i) in menus"
                  :id="'menuNo'+i"
                  :key="i"
                  >
                  <router-link
                     class="nav-link"
                     :to="menuItem.state"
                     v-if="menuItem.type == 'link'"
                     @click.native="removeCollapseInClass();"
                  >
                     {{ menuItem.name }}
                  </router-link>
                  <a
                     v-if="menuItem.type == 'sub'"
                     class="nav-link"
                     href="javascript:void(0)"
                  >
                     {{ menuItem.name }}&nbsp;
                     <i :class="menuItem.icon" @click.stop="menuToggle('menuNo'+i)"></i>
                  </a>
                  <ul
                     v-if="menuItem.type == 'sub' && menuItem.children"
                     class="sub-menu arrow-up list-unstyled" >
                     <li
                        class="nav-item"
                        v-for="(grandchildItem,i) of menuItem.children"
                        :key="i"
                        >
                        <router-link
                           class="nav-link"
                           :to="grandchildItem.state"
                           v-if="grandchildItem.type == 'link'"
                           @click.native="removeCollapseInClass()"
                        >
                           {{ grandchildItem.name }}
                        </router-link>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <div
                     class="search-form"
                     click-outside
                  >
                     <span
                        data-target="#search-style-simple"
                        @click="showSearch()"
                     >
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                     </span>
                     <div
                        class="module-container"
                        :class="{'search-active': searchactive}"
                        id="search-style-simple"
                     >
                        <form role="search" method="get" class="search-box" action="javascript:void(0);">
                           <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" value="" name="" />
                           <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                        </form>
                     </div><!-- /module-container -->
                  </div><!-- /module -->
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </nav>
</template>
<script>
   export default{
      data(){
         return{
            searchactive:false,
            menus: [
               {
                  state: "/home",
                  name: "Home",
                  type:"link"
               },
               {
                  state:"",
                  name:"Pages",
                  type:"sub",
                  icon: 'fa fa-caret-down',
                  children: [
                     { state: 'about', name: 'About', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'features', name: 'Features', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'contact', name: 'Contact', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'pricing', name: 'Pricing', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'search', name: 'Search', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'portfolio-v1', name: 'Products V1', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'portfolio-v2', name: 'Products V2', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'portfolio-v3', name: 'Products V3', type:"link"}
                  ]
               },
               {
                  state:"",
                  name:"Features",
                  type:"sub",
                  icon: 'fa fa-caret-down',
                  children: [
                     { state: 'login', name:'Login', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'sign-up', name: 'Sign Up', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'thank-you', name: 'Thank You', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'maintenance', name: 'Maintenance', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'not-found', name: '404', type:"link"}
                  ]
               },
               {
                  state:"",
                  name:"Shop",
                  type:"sub",
                  icon: 'fa fa-caret-down',
                  children: [
                     { state: 'product-grid', name:'Product Grid', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'product-cart', name: 'Product Cart', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'product-checkout', name: 'Product Checkout', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'product-detail', name: 'Product Detail', type:"link"}
                  ]
               },
               {
                  state:"",
                  name:"Blog",
                  type:"sub",
                  icon: 'fa fa-caret-down',
                  children: [
                     { state: 'blog-listing-sidebar', name:'blog column ', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'blog-column3', name: 'Blog Column1', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'blog-masonry3', name: 'Blog Masonry', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'blog-sidebar', name: 'Blog Sidebar', type:"link"},
                     { state: 'blog-detail', name: 'Blog Detail', type:"link"}
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      mounted(){
         this.onScrollEvent();
      },
      methods:{
         showSearch(){
            this.searchactive = !this.searchactive;
         },
         menuToggleLink(id){
            if (document.getElementById(id).classList.contains("open")){
               document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("open");
            } else if(!document.getElementById(id).classList.contains("open")) {
               let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".parent");
               for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                  elements[i].classList.remove('open');
               }
               document.getElementById(id).classList.add("open");
            }
         },
         addToggleClass(){
            document.querySelector("body").classList.toggle("rtl-enable");
         },
         removeCollapseInClass(){
            document.getElementById("navbarCollapse").classList.remove('show');
         },
         onScrollEvent(){
            var headerSticky = document.getElementById('mainNav');
            window.onscroll = function() {
               if (window.pageYOffset >= 100) {
                  headerSticky.classList.add("scrollHeader");
               }  else {
                  headerSticky.classList.remove("scrollHeader");
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
</script>
<style>
   .scrollHeader{
      background-color: #0B3242;
   }
</style>
```